# Is it possible to change the BiDi mode of TScreenTipsWindow?

Tags: delphi

I'd like to use `TScreenTipsManager` to display office-style hint windows in my applications, but so far I have been unable to access the private member `FWnd: TScreenTipsWindow` to change it's `BiDiMode` because it's declared **private**. Can I create a descendant of `TScreenTipsWindow`, change it's `BiDiMode`, and pass it to the `ScreenTipsManager` in the `OnGetScreenTipWinClass` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly fine. That's what the [`OnGetScreenTipWinClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ScreenTips.TScreenTipsManager.OnGetScreenTipWinClass) event is for. You'll just pass your own [`TScreenTipsWindowClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ScreenTips.TScreenTipsWindowClass) class descendant to the `ScreenTipWinClass` event parameter and this class will be used to instantiate the hint window.

If you wouldn't handle that event or change the class in its parameter, the default [`TScreenTipsWindow`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ScreenTips.TScreenTipsWindow) class would be used for a hint window.

Comment: Thanks. Am I right in assuming that I have to completely override `Paint` in my descendant class? I believe changing the `BiDiMode` does not have that much of effect.

Comment: In `TScreenTipsWindow.CreateParams` there's the [`AddBiDiModeExStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.AddBiDiModeExStyle) method call, which should adjust the window bi-di mode according to control's settings, so maybe it's really enough to access the [`BiDiMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.BiDiMode) property.

Comment: And if the previous won't work, then you will have to override the `Paint` method, since it uses [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) function for text rendering, ignoring the `DT_RTLREADING` flag.

Comment: I'm creating my own `HintWindow` class to avoid using `ScreenTipsManager` and `ScreenTipsWindow`. I've extracted `TSreenTipsWindow` from `Vcl.ScreenTips` and am in the process of modifying it to be usable as `HintWindow`. This way, I don't have to worry about diffences between _normal_ hint windows and those shown by `ScreenTipsManager`

Comment: The `TSreenTipsWindow` might IMHO be used as `HintWindow` hence it's a `THintWindow` descendant.

Comment: I tried assigning `TScreenTipsWindow` to `HintWindowClass`, but it resulted to an access violation every time a hint were to be displayed.. I believe `TScreenTipsWindow` tries to find a `TScreenTipsManager` to read properties such as _footer_, _help icon_, etc. from it.